# Access list of all apps currently using hardware features

Tags: android, security, camera

is there a possibility to access the number or even the name of apps and processes using some hardware elements such as camera or mic in Android?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go about this would be to first find apps with features and then find the corresponding pid. If you are not root I don't think it is possible to get system services. Also getting pid is difficult. 
Have a look at this [github link](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses).It works only below Android N.

Apps need to have permission declared to use hardware in their manifest.
For example, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO to record audio or android.permission.CAMERA to use camera.

For more information on Permissions have a look at this official google [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html).

```
String[] permissions = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("Enter Your PackageName Here", PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
.requestedPermissions

for (String permission : permissions) {
    if(permission.equals("hardware permission like camera or record audio")){
        //Do Stuff here
       //Use the methods given in the gihtub link above to get PID  
      //Below code is take from the github link given above 
        List<AndroidAppProcess> processes =AndroidProcesses.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (AndroidAppProcess process : processes) {
          // Get some information about the process
          String processName = process.name;

          Stat stat = process.stat();
          int pid = stat.getPid();
          int parentProcessId = stat.ppid();
          long startTime = stat.stime();
          int policy = stat.policy();
          char state = stat.state();

          Statm statm = process.statm();
          long totalSizeOfProcess = statm.getSize();
          long residentSetSize = statm.getResidentSetSize();

          PackageInfo packageInfo = process.getPackageInfo(context, 0);
          String appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Manually if you want to check run adb shell and via top check if the corresponding uid is running.